# Custom sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql

Say i have an image :

[image]

This signifies that 1 has friends 2,3,4 and 6 is also the friend of 1.

How do i get these ids 2,3,4 and 6 that are friends with 1 using **SQL**

Comment: A side note: id1 and id2 are awful column names.

Comment: I am sorry just done that for testing purposes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that depends a bit on which DB you are using - the following will work in MySQL and Oracle and perhaps in MS SQL server (not sure):

```
SELECT 
(CASE WHEN ID1 = 1 THEN ID2 ELSE ID1 END) AS THEFRIENDS 
FROM YOURTABLE WHERE 
ID2 = 1 OR 
ID1 = 1
```

This one works everywhere but is perhaps less performant:

```
SELECT ID1 FROM YOURTABLE WHERE ID2 = 1
UNION
SELECT ID2 FROM YOURTABLE WHERE ID1 = 1
```

Answer (score 2):

```
select id2 as FriendID from table
where id1 = 1
union
select id1 as FriendID from table
where id2 = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use more descriptive names for starters

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE id1=1 or id2=1 and id1<>id2
```

Comment: i thought these relations were identical

Comment: judging from the image in the question I would NOT assume they are identical... the edited version will show 1 as a friend of 1 too which is NOT what the OP asked !

Comment: the query from the second edit won't change any of the problems described !